# Change listbox selected item color in xaml Windows 8

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I am developing a windows 8 xaml application , I want to change the color of a selected text of textblock contained in a datatemplate of listbox dynamically, I had tried a lot to solve this problem.please help me to find a solution.

Here is my code

```
   <Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxBorderThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxBorderThemeThickness}"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Enabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                        <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxFocusBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ScrollViewer">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>

                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Style="{StaticResource ScrollViewerStyle1}" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}">
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>


<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle2" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,10"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedDisabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemSelectedDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid x:Name="InnerGrid" Background="Transparent">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="PressedBackground" Fill="{StaticResource ListBoxItemPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" Opacity="0"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset=".5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

<ListBox Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}" ItemContainerStyle={StaticResource  ListBoxItemStyle2} >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel x:Name="stackOuter" Width="327" Height="56" Margin="-7,-9,-7,-10" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <StackPanel.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush  ImageSource="/Assets/Images/categ_bg.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"></ImageBrush>
                                </StackPanel.Background>
                                <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#a7a7a7" FontWeight="Light" FontFamily="sego WP" FontSize="21" Margin="25,15,0,0" Text="{Binding categoryName}">
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: What you had _tried_ ? post your code first.

Comment: following is my code :

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do following changes in current code.

1). In style `ListBoxItemStyle2`, find `<ContentPresenter .../>` add `Tag="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}"` in `<ContentPresenter .../>`

2). Remove static `Foreground="#a7a7a7"` property value from `ListBox`'s `DataTemplate`and add this

```xml
Foreground="{Binding Tag, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToColourConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
```

3). You need to use converter to set the foreground based on `IsSelected` property. If item is selected it will show green color otherwise red.

```
public sealed class BooleanToColourConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (value is bool && (bool)value) ? new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green) : new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value is SolidColorBrush && ((SolidColorBrush)value).Color == Windows.UI.Colors.Green;
    }
}
```

4). Add `<local:BooleanToColourConverter x:Key="BooleanToColourConverter"/>` in `<Page.Resources>`.